# NoSuchGroupException: No Group exists with the key {companyId=20116, friendlyURL=site1}

Tags: liferay

I manually created a site in Liferay, and want to get its object from a Java Liferay module. If I understand correctly, a site is represented by the `Group` class. So I wrote this:

```
Group group = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLGroup(
                                          Utils.getCompanyId(), "site1");
```

Problem: I get this exception:

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.NoSuchGroupException: No Group exists with the key {companyId=20116, friendlyURL=site1}
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.GroupPersistenceImpl.findByC_F(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:3563)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.getFriendlyURLGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:1141)
```

I am 100% sure that `site1` exists. The exception still happens after I reindex all in "Server Administration".

[image: Friendly URL]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is perfect but when you lookup with friendly URL. You should pass friendly URL in param like "/site1"

```
Group group = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLGroup(
                                          Utils.getCompanyId(), "/site1");
```